# Jenkins ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jenkinsapi.jenkins'; 'jenkinsapi' is not a package

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a virtual machine running Centos 6. I have a simple python script I am trying to run in Jenkins. I can run the script successfully on the virtual machine, but I cannot run the script once it exists in Jenkins Workspace.

```
[root@vm921.dev.ut1 ~]# /usr/local/bin/python3.7
Python 3.7.0 (default, Mar 20 2019, 14:31:35)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
>>>
```

As you can see above, I can import jenkinsapi module successfully from the command line, I just cant run it in Jenkins.

I have python3.7 installed with pip3.7. The jenkinsapi package exists but I cannot execute the script from workspace directories.

```
    [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/jenkinsapi
[jenkinsapi] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5545466490229682574.sh
+ cd /home/ccuevas
+ pip3 install jenkinsapi
Requirement already satisfied: jenkinsapi in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2014.4 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jenkinsapi) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jenkinsapi) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jenkinsapi) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->jenkinsapi) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->jenkinsapi) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->jenkinsapi) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.3.0->jenkinsapi) (2.8)
+ python3 jenkins.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jenkins.py", line 1, in <module>
    from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jenkinsapi'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried uninstalling jenkinsapi package and reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

After much toil, I resolved the issue. The problem was the file name for my job in Jenkins was named 'jenkinsapi.py'. The job was trying to import the file itself instead of the 'jenkinsapi' module from the first line 'import jenkinsapi'. I renamed the file in Jenkins to something else and there error is no longer occurring.